# How to test Axios calls without mocks

Tags: testing, axios, jestjs

Is there a way to run tests with Jest and avoid mocking axios? I'd like to run tests that actually use axios to make http requests, rather than mocking them. If there is not a way to do this, are there recommended ways of testing these calls without Jest?

The reason I'd like to truly run the http requests rather than mock them is that I don't want the endpoints to either change their url without me knowing, or change the data that they expect in both the request and response. Otherwise, it is not obvious if they change if I just mock them every time.

Comment: If you don't mock Axios, it will make real HTTP requests. What problem are you running into with this approach?

Comment: I keep getting the error "Syntax error: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Comment: Sounds more like a Jest configuration issue